# not able to create hotspot in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

I am tried using following method , but phone is not detecting this hotspot
https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html

can anybody help me?

Comment: What system does the phone use? Default Android does not work with AD-HOC connections http://stackoverflow.com/a/5102833/1437269

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/748455/how-to-setup-access-point-wifi-hotspot-on-debian this link help me. you can try.

Answer (score 8):

I have tried [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) tutorial and for me it works great. Also I can connect to Ubuntu from Android and any device.

1. Disable WIFI and plug in an internet cable to your laptop so that your Ubuntu is connect to a wired internet and wireless is disabled.
2. Go to Network Icon on top panel -> Edit Connections …, then click the **Add** button in the pop-up window.
3. Choose **Wi-Fi** from the drop-down menu when you’re asked to choose a connection type:
4. In next window, do:
   Type in a connection name. The name will be used later. Type in a **SSID**, Select **mode: Infrastructure** , **Device MAC address:** select your wireless card from drop-down menu.
5. Go to **Wi-Fi Security** tab, select security type **WPA & WPA2 Personal** and set a password.
6. Go to **IPv4 Settings** tab, from Method drop-down box select **Shared to other computers**.

   When done, click the **save** button.

After above steps, a configuration file created under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory. File name is same to the connection name you typed in step 4.

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> on keyboard to open terminal. When it opens, paste the commands below and hit enter to edit the configuration file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi-hotspot
```

Replace `wifi-hotspt` with the connection name you typed in step 4.

When the file opens, find out the line `mode=infrastructure` and change it to `mode=ap`. Finally save the file.

When everything’s done, enable WIFI from Network Manager icon on the panel. It should automatically connect to the hotspot you created. If not, select “**Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network …**” and select it from the drop-down box.

Done.

Comment: Thank you! This method works for me.  In my edit connections window, I can directly choose hotspot from the mode.  Then I don't need to edit the mode in the configuration file in the last step.

Comment: (2018) Step 4 - chose `hotspot`, instructions after step 6 wasn't needed.

Comment: Thanks! This technique works but WITHOUT INTERNET CONNECTION. Every time I turn on the hotspot, Ubuntu cannot connect to the wired internet connection.

Answer (score 4):

I had to install `dnsmasq` and restart `NetworkManager` service to get hot spot working:

```
sudo apt install dnsmasq
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

And, network management in gnome control center didn't allow me to create custom wifi profile. So, I used `nmtui`.

Comment: It was `dnsmasq`.

Comment: For me as well, turning on "Use as Hotspot" was crashing for me until I installed dnsmasq. After that, all was fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't work on my Ubuntu 16.04.  In addition, after installing dnsmasq, network manager somehow use 100% cpu when I turn on my wifi.

Answer (score 1):

System Settings --> Network --> Wired :- Make it on --> Wireless --> Use as Hotspot --> Create Hotspot --> Options --> Wireless --> Give name --> Wireless Security --> Give password --> IP4v4 Settings --> Method --> Shared with other computers --> Save

See:

http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

NOTE: You cannot simultaneously connect to a wifi network as well as create a hotspot

Answer (score 0):

If you can't still get it to work, see the logs

```
systemctl status network-manager
```

In my logs I had

```
hotspot audit: op="connection-add-activate result="fail" reason="802-11-wireless.ssid: SSID length is out of range
```

Error suggests that name of my hotspot (ssid) is out of range, the name of hotspot is your computer's (system) name itself, and mine was like 25 characters so it wasn't working. So I reduced it to 5-6 characters and now it works fine.

Comment: Where are the logs for networking saved?